# How to print Firestore timestamp as formatted date and time

Tags: time, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My timestamp returns `Timestamp(seconds=1560523991, nanoseconds=286000000)` in a Flutter Firestore snapshot.

I want to print it as properly formatted date and time.

I'm using `DateTime.now()` to store current DateTime in Firestore while creating new records and retrieving it using Firestore snapshot but I am not able to convert to into formatted date time. I'm using lib `intl.dart` for formatting.

Code for saving data

```
       d={'amount':amount,
      'desc':desc,
      'user_id':user_id,
      'flie_ref':url.toString(),
      'date':'${user_id}${DateTime.now().day}-${DateTime.now().month}-${DateTime.now().year}',
      'timestamp':DateTime.now()
return Firestore.instance.collection('/data').add(d).then((v){return true;
    }).catchError((onError)=>print(onError));
    });

Accessing with 

    FutureBuilder(
                  future: Firestore.instance
                      .collection('data')
                      .where('user_id', isEqualTo:_user_id)
                      .getDocuments(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData)
                      return Container(
                          child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
       Text(DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(DateTime.parse(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['timestamp'].toString())]);


....
```

Error thrown is

> Invalid date format.

I'm expecting output is: `'Jan 17, 2019, 2:19 PM'`

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972765/how-to-read-firestore-timestamp-in-flutter

Comment: i have to use this way ```snapshot.data.documents[index].data['timestamp'].toDate() ```???

Answer (score 49):

When we push the *DateTime* object to Firestore, it internally converts it to it's own *timestamp* object and stores it.

**Method to convert it back to Datetime after fetching timestamp from Firestore:**

Firestore's *timestamp* contains a method called *toDate()* which can be converted to String and then that String can be passed to *DateTime*'s *parse* method to convert back to *DateTime*

```
DateTime.parse(timestamp.toDate().toString())
```

Comment: I think we don't first need to convert the timestamp.toDate() to string and then parse the string to get the actual DateTime. You can simply do timestamp.toDate(). It already returns the DateTime.

Comment: "parse" doesn't exist...? I did this - myDate = DateFormat('dd-MMM-yy ~ HH:mm').format(data['itemDate'].toDate()).toString(),

Answer (score 27):

Here is way!

Firestore will return TimeStamp like Timestamp(seconds=1560523991, nanoseconds=286000000).

This can be parsed as

```
Timestamp t = document['timeFieldName'];
DateTime d = t.toDate();
print(d.toString()); //2019-12-28 18:48:48.364
```

Comment: .toDate() is a Timestamp function. Timestamp is provided by Firebase cloud firestore not by default flutter material.Try by import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Comment: getDateTimeFromTimestamp(int timestampInSeconds) {
    var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestampInSeconds * 1000);
    return date;
  } DateTime lastPostedMessageOnDateTime = getDateTimeFromTimestamp(document['timeFieldName'].seconds); It worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can directly convert the Firestore timestamp object to DateTime like this:

```
DateTime myDateTime = (snapshot.data.documents[index].data['timestamp']).toDate();
```

This will return your Firestore timestamp in the dart's DateTime format. In order to convert your `DateTime` object you can use `DateFormat` class from [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl#-readme-tab-) package.
You can use your obtained DateTime object to get the format of your choice like this:

```
DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(myDateTime);
```

This code produces an output like this:

```
Apr 21, 2020 5:33 PM
```

Answer (score 6):

timestamp parameter is the time in seconds

```
String formatTimestamp(int timestamp) {
      var format = new DateFormat('d MMM, hh:mm a');
      var date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
      return format.format(date);
    }
```

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126579/how-do-i-format-a-date-with-dart) answer for intl date formats

Hope it helps !

Comment: for formatTimestamp() to pass I m not getting data in int type, i m getting data as Timestamp(seconds=1560523991, nanoseconds=286000000) this format

Answer (score 4):

I found Ashutosh's suggestion gives more user friendly output. A function like this is recommended in a helper class with a static method.

```
  static convertTimeStamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
    assert(timestamp != null);
    String convertedDate;
    convertedDate = DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(timestamp.toDate());
    return convertedDate;
  }
```

[Intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl#-readme-tab-) package is require for `DateFormat`.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've got a **timestamp** back from Firestore, something like

> Timestamp(seconds=1560523991, nanoseconds=286000000)

you need to **parse** it into an object of type DateTime:

`DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.parse(timestamp.toDate().toString());`

```
 print('$myDateTime');
```

This will give you something like:

> 2020-05-09 15:27:04.074

You can then format myDateTime like this:

```
String formattedDateTime =
          DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(myDateTime);

print('$formattedDateTime');
```

That will give you:

> 2020-05-09 – 15:27

Answer (score 2):

Use [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package:

```dart
Timestamp firebaseTimestamp = ...;
var date = firebaseTimestamp.toDate();

var output1 = DateFormat('MM/dd, hh:mm a').format(date); // 12/31, 10:00 PM
var output2 = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(date); // Dec 31, 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get a unix timestamp from firestore even if you send a DateTime to firestore.

You can parse a DateTime from Firestore with `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);`

The DateTime class has two option to return a sting. `toIso8601String()` or `toString()`
choose the one you need. Or use eg. DateTime.now().hour; to get the our and create your own output.

For more information: Check https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Comment: i m getting timestamp as ```Timestamp(seconds=1560523991, nanoseconds=286000000)``` format so tell me how to use that

Comment: Did you tried it? I'm sure that I used it in that way. Unfortunately I can not check that at the moment.

Comment: I m getting timestamp as object

Comment: @aryan singh Please check my answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using cloud firestore, Here's my what worked for me:

```
Text(snapshot.data["YouKey"].toDate().toString().substring(0,16))
```

subString is optionnal, I've added it because I had the clock time with many number after the minute (like 12:00 00:00:00)

Answer (score 1):

It took a long time to find the perfect answer.
When you fetch the data from Firestore as a Timestamp object and you are sure about that then I will recommend you use the following code:

```
DateTime fetchedDate = e.data()["deadline"]?.toDate();
```

using `?.toDate()` worked for me and hopefully will also work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Timestamp t = document['time'] // Timestamp(seconds=1624653319,nanoseconds=326000000)
DateTime d = t.toDate();
print(d.toString()); //2021-06-25 18:48:48.364
```

Comment: Give some description to explain your code. Have a look on [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

There are  different ways this can be achieved based on different scenario, see which of the following code fits your scenario.

##### Conversion of `Firebase timestamp` to `DateTime`:

1. ```
   document['timeStamp'].toDate()
   ```
2. ```
   (document["timeStamp"] as Timestamp).toDate()
   ```
3. ```
   DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(document['timeStamp'].millisecondsSinceEpoch);
   ```
4. ```
   Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(document['timeStamp'].millisecondsSinceEpoch).toDate();
   ```
5. If `timeStamp` is in `microseconds` use:

   ```
   DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000000);
   ```
6. If `timeStamp` is in `milliseconds` use:

   ```
   DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
   ```
7. Add the following function in your dart file.

   ```
    String formatTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
      var format = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); // <- use skeleton here
      return format.format(timestamp.toDate());
    }
   ```

call it as `formatTimestamp(document['timestamp'])`

---

###### Note: To print this `DateTime` append `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Do like so:

```
DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(DateTime.parse(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['timestamp'].toDate().toString())]
```

Comment: could you please provide some additional explanation to support your answer?

Comment: This answer uses intl library. Please use the link here to find out how this answer works. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Answer (score 0):

First visit [here](https://pub.dev/packages/intl#-installing-tab-) for intl package,
then paste the package into your pubspec.yaml, run pub get (the usual way of updating pubspec).Import the package into your dart file and try out the below method.

```
String timestamp;

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formatDate =
    DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(now);
timestamp = formatDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch** function.

```
var d = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(ts, isUtc: true);
```

Here ts is int type.

So we can convert Firebase **timestamps** to DateTime object as follows.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp.seconds * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to solve it.

//Declare a variable Timestamp and assign the value timestamp from database

```
Timestamp timestamp = document['timeFieldName'];
```

//Use DateTime's parse method to convert back to DateTime

```
DateTime _time =DateTime.parse(timestamp.toDate().toString())
```

//Use this method to get the H:m of the DateTime.
//You can choose the `DateFormat` you want.

```
String readTimeStamp(DateTime date)
  {
    
     var format =new DateFormat.Hm(); // My Format 08:00

     return format.format(date);
  }
```