# How do I resolve type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch meetings from Firestore and map them into the following `Meeting` model:

```
part 'meeting.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Meeting {
  String id;
  DateTime date;

  Meeting(this.id, this.date);

  factory Meeting.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    return _$MeetingFromJson(json);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MeetingToJson(this);
}
```

The documents are fetched from Firestore and then `fromJson` is called on the iterable, but an exception is thrown:

```
type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

When I go into generated `meeting.g.dart`, it's this line which causes the error

```
json['date'] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json['date'] as String)
```

To workaround the issue, I've tried changing from DateTime to Timestamp in the model, but then the following build error is shown:

```
Error running JsonSerializableGenerator
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `date`.
None of the provided `TypeHelper` instances support the defined type.
```

Could you tell me how do you solve this issue?
Is there another preferred way to combine Firebase and a Flutter project using  json_serializable  for JSON serialization? Maybe even replace usage of  json_serializable ?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `DateTime.parse(json['date'] as String)`. With `DateTime.parse(json['date'].toString())`

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice to edit generated files. I would have to do this every time the model changes, because the meeting.g.dart would be re-generated.

Comment: You might have to serialize the json manually, take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/58309472/9609442

Comment: In app in production I parse dateline to string before upload it, then convert it back to date time when fetch it.

Comment: What are you getting in json['date'] ? Is it millisecondsSinceEpoch or dateString?

Comment: Could you please try with the following : json['date'].toDate() and let me know if it works ?

Comment: How did you define date typed field in dart model? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution #1

Use `toJson` and `fromJson` converter functions as in the following example: https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/master/example/lib/example.dart

Benefits of the solution is that you don't have to hard-code property names

## Solution #2

After reading https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/issues/351, I've changed `Meeting.fromJson` and it works as expected now:

```
  factory Meeting.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    json["date"] = ((json["date"] as Timestamp).toDate().toString());
    return _$MeetingFromJson(json);
  }
```

`json["date"]` is `Timestamp` by default, I convert it to `String`, before it reaches the generated deserializer, so it doesn't crash when it tries to cast `json["date"] as String`

Though, I don't like this workaround very much, because I have to hard-code property's name and couple to types, but for now, this solution will be good enough.

An alternative would be to try out https://pub.dev/packages/built_value for serialiazion, which is recommended in their blog https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: Glad it helped. Have you tried the solution from this example https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/master/example/lib/example.dart ?

Comment: Had to go with the `@JsonKey(fromJson: _dateTime, toJson: _dateTime)` to simply  letting the `json_annotation` library ignore `DateTime` massaging. That way firestore will properly handle this field as timestamp. `static DateTime _dateTime(DateTime dateTime) => dateTime;`

Comment: How did you defined date/timestamp typed field in dart model? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Timestamp is a type from cloud_firestore library

Answer (score 38):

Use [JsonConverter](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/master/example/lib/json_converter_example.dart)

```
class TimestampConverter implements JsonConverter<DateTime, Timestamp> {
  const TimestampConverter();

  @override
  DateTime fromJson(Timestamp timestamp) {
    return timestamp.toDate();
  }

  @override
  Timestamp toJson(DateTime date) => Timestamp.fromDate(date);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class User{
  final String id;
  @TimestampConverter()
  final DateTime timeCreated;

  User([this.id, this.timeCreated]);

  factory User.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) =>
      _$UserFromJson(
          documentSnapshot.data..["_id"] = documentSnapshot.documentID);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this)..remove("_id");
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks. This is also compatible with [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed). Other solutions above are overcomplicating the issue.

Comment: @AlexHartford ?

Comment: @ValentinSeehausen You are able to use the @TimestampConverter() decorator with a freezed class just like you can with a JsonSerializable class. It works exactly the same way.

Comment: @AlexHartford Thanks for the answer. Did you test it with the current, nullsafe versions? Somehow it did not work for me.

Comment: @ValentinSeehausen Yes, can you open a question and post your code? I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: Hey @AlexHartford, thanks for you support. I copied a question at [GitHub](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/15#issuecomment-822482887) and posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150713/freezed-and-json-serializable-how-to-use-a-custom-converter). Looking forward to your comments.

Comment: How did you defined date/timestamp typed field in dart model with NULL Safety? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @Reed, for pointing to the right direction. When passing `DateTime` value to `FireStore` there seem no issues for firebase to take that value as `Timestamp`, however when getting it back it needs to be properly handled.  Anyways, here is example, that works both ways:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'; //<-- dependency referencing Timestamp
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'test_date.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(anyMap: true)
class TestDate {

  @JsonKey(fromJson: _dateTimeFromTimestamp, toJson: _dateTimeAsIs)
  final DateTime theDate; 


  TestDate({this.theDate,});

   factory TestDate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {     
     return _$TestDateFromJson(json);
   } 
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TestDateToJson(this);

  static DateTime _dateTimeAsIs(DateTime dateTime) => dateTime;  //<-- pass through no need for generated code to perform any formatting

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627888/how-to-print-firestore-timestamp-as-formatted-date-and-time-in-flutter
  static DateTime _dateTimeFromTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
    return DateTime.parse(timestamp.toDate().toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, but `json_serializer` still wasn't converting the `Timestamp` objects because some of them were `nullable`.

```
// nullable
class TimestampConverter implements JsonConverter<DateTime?, Timestamp?> {
  const TimestampConverter();

  @override
  DateTime? fromJson(Timestamp? timestamp) => timestamp?.toDate();

  @override
  Timestamp? toJson(DateTime? date) => date == null ? null : Timestamp.fromDate(date);
}
```

Also, I like to put the additional `id` field in the stream `method` so it looks cleaner in the class. In my case, I just save the `DocumentReference`.

```
Stream<User> streamUser() {
  return user().snapshots().map(
    (snapshot) {
      try {
        return User.fromDocument(snapshot);
      } catch (e) {
        FirebaseWorker().signOut();
        rethrow;
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Lastly, I had multiple `DateTime` properties so I was able to put `@TimestampConverter` at the top of the class.

And you can ignore properties so that it doesn't get serialized when calling `toJson` with `@JsonKey(ignore: true)`.

So final code looks like this:

```
@TimestampConverter() // <--
class User{
  @JsonKey(ignore: true) // <--
  final String id;
  final DateTime? birthday;
  final DateTime timeCreated;

  User([this.id, this.timeCreated]);

  factory UserProfile.empty() => UserProfile(id: '', timeCreated: DateTime.now());

  factory UserProfile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserProfileFromJson(json);

  factory UserProfile.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) 
  {
    final data = documentSnapshot.data();
    return data != null
        ? UserProfile.fromJson(data as Map<String, dynamic>)
            ..reference = documentSnapshot.reference
        : UserProfile.empty();

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this); // <-- don't need to remove id anymore
  }
```