# Freezed and json_serializable: How to use a custom converter

Tags: flutter, freezed, json-serializable

I want to add a custom converter to a freezed class like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60793441/how-do-i-resolve-type-timestamp-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-string-in-type-cast).

I tried it with this code:

```
@freezed
class NewsPost with _$NewsPost {
  factory NewsPost({
    @JsonKey(name: "date") @TimestampConverter() DateTime? date,
  }) = _NewsPost;

  factory NewsPost.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$NewsPostFromJson(json);
}
```

But it did not work. Any ideas are more than welcome!

For your interest, this is my Converter:

```
class TimestampConverter implements JsonConverter<DateTime, Timestamp> {
  const TimestampConverter();

  @override
  DateTime fromJson(Timestamp timestamp) {
    return timestamp.toDate();
  }

  @override
  Timestamp toJson(DateTime date) => Timestamp.fromDate(date);
}
```

Thank you :-)

Comment: Can you expand on "did not work"? Your code is correct.

Comment: @valentin-seehausen please see more reply on the issue you commented on in the freezed repo: https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/15#issuecomment-828182464

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since null safety was introduced, for `JsonConverter` to work with the  `freezed` generator the nullability of the types declared in `JsonConverter` need to match the nullability of the type in the freezed class.

If the types do not match, `freezed` ignores the converter.

So using your example:

```
@freezed
class NewsPost with _$NewsPost {
  factory NewsPost({
    @TimestampOrNullConverter() DateTime? date, // <-- this is nullable, so the converter needs to handle null
    @TimestampConverter() DateTime createdAt, // <-- not nullable, so your exsiting converter will work
  }) = _NewsPost;

  factory NewsPost.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$NewsPostFromJson(json);
}

class TimestampConverter implements JsonConverter<DateTime, Timestamp> {
  const TimestampConverter();

  @override
  DateTime fromJson(Timestamp timestamp) {
    return timestamp.toDate();
  }

  @override
  Timestamp toJson(DateTime date) => Timestamp.fromDate(date);
}

class TimestampOrNullConverter implements JsonConverter<DateTime?, Timestamp?> {
  const TimestampOrNullConverter();

  @override
  DateTime? fromJson(Timestamp? timestamp) {
    return timestamp?.toDate();
  }

  @override
  Timestamp? toJson(DateTime? date) => date == null ? null : Timestamp.fromDate(date);
}
```

Tested and working on flutter 2.5.3 with the following dependency versions:

```
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.1.4
  freezed: ^0.15.0+1
  json_serializable: ^5.0.2
```

Answer (score 13):

Well, it´s not the most elegant solution, but it works.

```
@freezed
class NewsPost with _$NewsPost {
  factory NewsPost({
    @JsonKey(
       name: "date", 
       fromJson: dateTimeFromJson, 
       toJson: dateTimeToJson,
    ) DateTime? date,
  }) = _NewsPost;

  factory NewsPost.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$NewsPostFromJson(json);
}


DateTime dateTimeFromJson(Timestamp timestamp) {
    return timestamp.toDate();
}

Timestamp dateTimeToJson(DateTime date) => Timestamp.fromDate(date);
```

I think it´s a solution. Using JsonConverter I can't get it to work.