# Generate fromJson code for non valid json type

Tags: flutter, flutter-freezed

I am using `freezed.`

My code looks like this:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'key_state.freezed.dart';
part 'key_state.g.dart';

@freezed
class KeyState with _$KeyState {
  factory KeyState({
    CancelToken? token,
    // ...
  }) = _KeyState;

  factory KeyState.initial() => KeyState();

  factory KeyState.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$KeyStateFromJson(json);
}
```

This is the `CancelToken` class from https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/dio/lib/src/cancel_token.dart

This does not work.

Errors:

```
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `token`.
To support the type `CancelToken` you can:
* Use `JsonConverter`
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonConverter-class.html
* Use `JsonKey` fields `fromJson` and `toJson`
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonKey/fromJson.html
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonKey/toJson.html
package:flutter_app/redux/state/key_state.freezed.dart:114:22
```

How do I do this?

Comment: can you share `CancelToken` model class

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it is from Dio library https://pub.dev/packages/dio#cancellation

Comment: @YeasinSheikh https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/dio/lib/src/cancel_token.dart

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that the CancelToken class cannot be converted to JSON directly.  Your options are:

1. Build a service class that converts your KeyState class into a JSON representation manually.
2. Create an extension method for the CancelToken class in your project, which adds the fromJson and toJson methods to it.
   https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods
3. Fork the code from Github, add the conversion methods to the CancelToken class yourself, and reference your repo in your pubspec.yaml file.
   (also, submit a pull request to merge your changes into the original repo)

You will also need to add similar conversion methods for dependant types like DioError, RequestOptions, Response.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I don't know how to do it. Can you please share how to Build a service class that converts your KeyState class into a JSON representation manually.

Comment: can you please post an example of number 2? thank you

Comment: Any workaround on this?

Comment: this is an example of a JsonConverter service:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69749532/13801829