# Could not generate `fromJson` code for `images` because of type `Asset`

Tags: json, flutter, jsonserializer, freezed, flutter-freezed

I am using freezed with json generator. i am facing this error on generating the code.

> Could not generate `fromJson` code for `images` because of type
> `Asset`.

**The Code Is:**

```
abstract class ProductDTO with _$ProductDTO {
  factory ProductDTO({
    required String description,
    required List<Asset> images, // error
  }) = _ProductDTO;

  // from Json
  factory ProductDTO.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ProductDTOFromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: if what you want is to load a list of images from the assets you can name the images with numbers ordered in such a way that when you want to have the list you can say i.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom data types require specific converters to handle their `toJson` and `fromJson` implementations. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150713/freezed-and-json-serializable-how-to-use-a-custom-converter) and its answers provide some nice examples.

Comment: When since they need a custom? cause before i update the libraries i was not getting that problem, and today, i got i!