# Flutter Freezed: generated code not calling toJson() on object from another package

Tags: flutter, freezed

I have a freezed class with the following fields:

```dart
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

part 'event.freezed.dart';
part 'event.g.dart';

@freezed
class Event with _$Event {
  const factory Event({
    required LatLng location,
    required DateTime date,
    required String name,
  }) = _Event;

  factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => _$EventFromJson(json);
}
```

Notice that the LatLng object comes from a package called `latlong2`. When I generate the code with build runner I get the following output.

```dart
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'event.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

_$_Event _$$_EventFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$_Event(
      location: LatLng.fromJson(json['location'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
      date: DateTime.parse(json['date'] as String),
      name: json['name'] as String,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$$_EventToJson(_$_Event instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'location': instance.location,
      'date': instance.date.toIso8601String(),
      'name': instance.name,
    };
```

For some reason json_serializable properly decodes the object but is unable to encode it because it doesn't call toJson() on `instance.location`. How did I fix this?

Comment: You might need a custom json converter, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150713/freezed-and-json-serializable-how-to-use-a-custom-converter

Comment: @Stephan Thanks! It is a bit annoying to write a converter that just calls the existing toJson method but it did fix my issue.