# Firebase FormatException: Invalid date format in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I have a Firestore Timestamp type field that I want to bring to my Flutter app, do some calculations, then print it on the screen. Everything is working fine for all other types besides the Timestamp. Here's my code (in a StaetefulWidget):

```
class _SummaryState extends State<Summary> {
  //Firebase
  var annual = DateTime.parse('2021-01-01');
  int overhaul = 5000;
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  void fetchAircraft() {
       firestoreInstance
        .collection("aircraft")
        .doc(aircraftID)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
       setState(() {
         overhaul = value.data()["engine"]["overhaul"];
String conversion = value.data()["lastAnnual"].toString();
print('timestamp: $conversion');
         annual = DateTime.parse(value.data()["lastAnnual"]);
       }
   }

   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     fetchAircraft();
   }
...code continues
```

Overhaul renders well but for the annual date, I get the error:

**I/flutter (23628): timestamp: Timestamp(seconds=1596254400, nanoseconds=0)
E/flutter (23628): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String'**

Any idea how to convert Timestamp from Firestore to Flutter? All I want is to use the date from the timestamp to calculate the time between the last inspection and set the new one.

Comment: I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627888/how-to-print-firestore-timestamp-as-formatted-date-and-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print Firestore timestamp as formatted date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627888/how-to-print-firestore-timestamp-as-formatted-date-and-time)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Firestore stores date and time in a [Timestamp](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp-class.html). Instead of using `toString()`, you can convert `Timestamp` to a [DateTime](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) object using [Timestamp.toDate()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp/toDate.html). You can then use the DateTime object to extract it in the format of your specification.