# How i can convert "Timestamp(seconds=1621176915, nanoseconds=276147000)" that is string type to actual timestamp type?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have fetched this timestamp from firebase and I want to convert this string timestamp to the actual datatype. But it gives me a parsing error that states below.

> Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp' in type cast

Comment: Timestamp is not a string. See "How to read Firestore timestamp in Flutter - Stack Overflow" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972765/how-to-read-firestore-timestamp-in-flutter

Comment: when i do this Firestore.instance.collection("yourCollectionName").snapshots(); it return me "Timestamp(seconds=1621176915, nanoseconds=276147000)"  . how i can convert this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632217/dart-flutter-converting-timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'; // for using Timestamp

final String preConverted = "Timestamp(seconds=1621176915, nanoseconds=276147000)";

final int _seconds =
        int.parse(preConverted.substring(18, 28)); // 1621176915
final int _nanoseconds =
        int.parse(preConverted.substring(42, preConverted.lastIndexOf(')'))); // 276147000
final Timestamp postConverted = Timestamp(_seconds, _nanoseconds);
```

Now you can get a Timestamp typed variable with postConverted.
I used a substring and lastIndexOf method and it worked for me.

Because of the nanoseconds can be 8 digits rather than 9 like this case, we need to use lastIndexOf method to take the index of ')' which represents the end of nanoseconds.

Comment: Thank you I did the same already. By the way good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to convert timestamp to a Datetime format, this is one way you can do it :

```
DateTime get date {
   if (timestamp != null) {
     return timestamp!.toDate();
  }
  return DateTime.now();      
}
```

Comment: No actually i want to convert "Timestamp(seconds=1621176915, nanoseconds=276147000)" that is string to timestamp object

Comment: Got it. Can I ask you why you want to save it as a timestamp data type and not as a datetime or string?

Comment: There is no timestamp object in flutter.

Comment: There is not but it is available in firebase packages

Comment: @VikramShetty If you know the answer then please comment here otherwise I can't tell you why I used Timestamp instead of DateTime

Comment: @HamzaMalik Got it. The only reason I asked was to see if we could different approach, but looking back I could have framed my question a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

(Firebase) Here are the ways you can convert that to traditional date string/object;

```
let datetime = timestamp.toDate()
```

Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp#methods

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) and to format the timestamp use this:

```
DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(timeStamp.toDate()) .toString(),
```